# Both videos keep reseting when 1 ends

Tags: xcode, swift, video

i have 2 mp4 videos playing on the screen, and both of them are supposed to loop. but they both reset at the same time, when 1 ends. how could i adjust my code so the videos loop separately?

```
    let videoURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("duda", withExtension: "mp4")!
    let sakeleURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("sakele_blikas", withExtension: "mp4")!


    player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
    player?.actionAtItemEnd = .None
    player?.muted = true

    player2 = AVPlayer(URL: sakeleURL)
    player2?.actionAtItemEnd = .None
    player2?.muted = true

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.zPosition = -1

    let playerLayer2 = AVPlayerLayer(player: player2)
    playerLayer2.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer2.zPosition = -1



    playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 100.0, width: 240.0, height: 433.0)
    playerLayer2.frame = CGRect(x:647.0, y: 90.0, width: 115.0, height: 44.0)

    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer2)
    player?.play()
    player2?.play()

    //loop video
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "loopVideo",
        name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
        object:nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loopvideo2", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)



}
```

func loopVideo(notification: NSNotification) {

```
if let finishedPlayer = notification.object as! AVPlayer!
{
    if finishedPlayer == self.player2
    {
      self.player2?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
      self.player2?.play()
    } else {
      self.player?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
      self.player?.play()
    }
}
```

}

heres the error code not sure how to format it

```
2016-02-08 16:44:15.222 Lietava 2[1928:361895] -[Lietava_2.display loopVideo]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14679cb0
```

2016-02-08 16:44:15.224 Lietava 2[1928:361895] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Lietava_2.display loopVideo]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14679cb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2138810b 0x20b2ee17 0x2138d925 0x2138b559 0x212bbc08 0x2133ce9d 0x2133c8a7 0x2133c685 0x213902db 0x2129ea53 0x2685604b 0x12b6c97 0x12b6c83 0x12bb76d 0x2134b3fd 0x213498f7 0x2129cbf9 0x2129c9e5 0x224e8ac9 0x2552cba1 0x114ea0 0x20f4b873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0):

So you have these two lines of code:

```
//loop video
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
    selector: "loopVideo",
    name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
    object:nil)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
    selector: "loopvideo2", 
    name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, 
    object: nil)
```

Which are actually registering two functions to be called for the exact same notification.  You're not actually determining there which video (or video player) has just finished up.

But you do have a way to do this.

The object passed along in the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` notification ["is the item that finished playing"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification).

Try doing:

```
func loopVideo(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let finishedPlayer = notification.object as AVPlayer!
    {
        if finishedPlayer == self.player2
        {
          self.player2?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
          self.player2?.play()
        } else {
          self.player1?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
          self.player1?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work, you need to make player1 and player2 properties of your view controller (instead of local variables that live only in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` functions).

Comment: hey, im getting an error now after the first full loop is finished, the app stops and xcode gives this error "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: does it say what line of code the exception is being thrown on, or a backtrace?

Comment: what is `Lietava_2.display`?  The name of your view controller or is it a property or?

Comment: its the name of the view controler

Comment: The method you're calling takes a parameter, so it needs a colon after the selector name. Make the selector "`loopVideo:`".  As in:  `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "loopVideo:", ....`